# matplotlib - Figure object has no attribute 'plot'. Reference problems

Tags: python, matplotlib

I know there are other people asking this question in their specific context, but none of those answers have gotten me closer to figuring this out. I am trying to use a class in matplotlib to add plots to a figure.

I'm trying to get the class to take as an argument a Line2D object and interpret it a bit - this is working. The class also registers a callback to mouse click events on the plot window - this is also working. Here's what's not working:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
series, = ax.plot(x_data, y_data)
classthing = MyClass(series)
plt.show()
```

And here is the class that is being instanced:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, series):
        self.series = series
        self.cid = series.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self)

    def __call__(self, event):
        self.series.figure.plot([xdata], [ydata])  
        self.series.figure.canvas.draw()
```

On mouse click I want to add a plot to the figure that I clicked on. This is really similar to the example here: https://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html

This code successfully creates the plot and the object, but obviously I'm not calling the plot() method from the correct reference since I get the title error on the second to last line. How can I reference the plot object properly given only the Line2D object that is in it? I am not anywhere near competent with OOP.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You don't plot on figures. You plot on axes that live in figures.

Answer (score 1):

You can't both plot an `ax` and use it again. The `series` in your code is a `Line2D` Object, which doesn't have an attribute `plot`.

What you can do is to add a `ax` object to your Class like this:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, series, fig):
        self.series = series
        self.figure = fig
        self.cid = self.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self)

    def __call__(self, event):
        self.series.plot([xdata], [ydata])  
        self.figure.canvas.draw()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
series = ax
classthing = MyClass(series)
classthing(some_event) # call your class
```

Now since you're passing an `ax` to the `class` your call will be successful, you still need to pass `xdata` and `ydata` to your call, though.

Since you'll be calling `figure` due to canvas draws, you'll need to pass that into your object as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I was able to get it working by just passing ax into the class. There's a lot I'm not getting about how event-oriented Python works. The purpose of this class is to gather some input data from the user before continuing to execute, but right now the script just finishes immediately even while the class waits for input. I need to find out how to force my script to wait for the callback to be completed x times, but I suppose that's another question.

Comment: Try `async` - but this would be a much larger subject